# Memory issue from UITable

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

My app is crashing because of a memory issue (Too much memory used). It happens when i open enough of the objects from the TableView. I has searched the internet for the problem, and i can see it might be because the memory never is released. But how do i release it?

Here is my code.

TableExerciseViewController

```
class TableExercisesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var choosenCellIndex = 0
var filteredExercises = [Exercise]()

let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Look up an exercise..."

    definesPresentationContext = true
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if let row = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(row, animated: false)
    }
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}




func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    filteredExercises = ExerciseManager.sharedInstance.getExercises().filter {
        exercise in return exercise.name.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}


//Returns the size of the arraylist
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


    if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        return filteredExercises.count
    }
    return ExerciseManager.sharedInstance.getExercises().count
}

//Returns the selected Cell
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Exercise Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ExerciseCustomCell
    let exercise: Exercise
    if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        exercise = filteredExercises[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        exercise = ExerciseManager.sharedInstance.getExercises()[indexPath.row]
    }

    cell.imgExercise?.image = exercise.exerciseImage1
    cell.lblExerciseName?.text = exercise.name
    cell.lblExerciseMuscleGroup?.text = exercise.muscle
    cell.lblExerciseTools?.text = "Equipment: \(exercise.tool)"

    return cell
}

 func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


//Sends the data through the selected identifier
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    choosenCellIndex = indexPath.row

    // Start segue with index of cell clicked
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Show Exercise", sender: self)

}

//Prepares the data for the segue and the next viewcontroller
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    // get a reference to the second view controller
    let exerciseViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ExerciseViewController

    // set a variable in the second view controller with the data to pass
    if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        exerciseViewController.exercise = filteredExercises[choosenCellIndex]
    } else {
        exerciseViewController.exercise = ExerciseManager.sharedInstance.getExercises()[choosenCellIndex]
    }

}

deinit {
    debugPrint("TableExerciseView deinitialized...")
}

}

extension TableExercisesViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!)
}
```

ExerciseViewController

```
class ExerciseViewController: UIViewController {
weak var exercise: Exercise?
var receivedCellIndex = 0

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

@IBOutlet weak var lblExerciseName: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var lblExerciseMuscleGroup: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var lblStartDescription: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var lblLastDescription: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var imgExerciseAnimation: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var imgExerciseStartPosition: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var imgExerciseLastPosition: UIImageView!

var timer = NSTimer()
var counter = 1


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Sets the color of the back button in navigation bar
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor();

    //Sets the labels
    lblExerciseName.text = exercise?.name
    lblExerciseMuscleGroup.text = exercise!.muscle
    lblStartDescription.text = "1. \(exercise!.startDescription)"
    lblLastDescription.text = "2. \(exercise!.lastDescription)"


    //Sets the antimation and the images
    imgExerciseAnimation.image = exercise?.exerciseImage1
    imgExerciseStartPosition.image = exercise?.exerciseImage1
    imgExerciseLastPosition.image = exercise?.exerciseImage2

    //Timer
    self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: #selector(ExerciseViewController.demonstrateExercise), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.timer.invalidate()
}

func demonstrateExercise() {
    if counter == 1 {
        imgExerciseAnimation.image = exercise?.exerciseImage2
        counter += 1
    } else {
        counter = 1
        imgExerciseAnimation.image = exercise?.exerciseImage1
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: by open enough od object you mean didSelectRow event ?

Comment: Yes, where it passes the segue. @Alok

Comment: How large is each image?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that what's taking up the memory are the exercise images in your ExerciseViewController. Since Swift uses [ARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting) to manage memory, you'll want to remove references to those images (and exercice for that matter) so that the system can release them from memory.

```
override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    lblExerciseName.text = nil
    lblExerciseMuscleGroup.text = nil
    lblStartDescription.text = nil
    lblLastDescription.text = nil

    imgExerciseAnimation.image = nil
    imgExerciseStartPosition.image = nil
    imgExerciseLastPosition.image = nil
}
```

Since your exercice variable is `weak`, and nothing is referencing to it, the system will now free it from memory instead of having multiple copies of exercices build up every time the user visits a new ExerciseViewController.

Comment: Hi @JeremyRea.
The issue still persist after updating the ViewDidDisappear function. Do you have any other suggestions or ideas?

Comment: @Jakob Does adding `exercise = nil` change anything?

Answer (score 0):

Override deinit function - and check if its called when you exit the Exercise view. If not - i would destroy the timer in viewWillDisappear or Did functions.

Comment: Everytime i exit the exercise view, the deinit function is called.

Comment: I have tested with and without the Timer - But the issue still persist.

Right now my viewDidDisappear function is looking like this:

        `super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        lblExerciseName.text = nil
        lblExerciseMuscleGroup.text = nil
        lblStartDescription.text = nil
        lblLastDescription.text = nil
        
        imgExerciseAnimation.image = nil
        imgExerciseStartPosition.image = nil
        imgExerciseLastPosition.image = nil
        
        self.timer.invalidate()`